# last-child:after not rendering in Chrome? Pseudo-element use issue?

Tags: html, css

I'm running into an issue with Chrome only (works fine in FF and Safari, not worrying about IE) that makes me wonder if this is a bug, if I'm using the pseudo elements incorrectly, or if you're not supposed to combine pseudo classes and pseudo elements.

What happens is that Chrome seems to see `content="-";` in the `last-child:after` rule, but doesn't render it. If I open the developer tools and fiddle with some of the properties (like turning the margin on and off), it suddenly shows up.

Here's the stripped down code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<div id="footer">
    <p>This is a footer</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul { text-align: center; }

#footer { text-align: center; margin-top: 200px;}

li:first-child:before, li:last-child:after, #footer:before {
    display: block;
    content: "-";
    color: red;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

**Also here:** http://jsfiddle.net/D4T6L/4/

It doesn't seem to make a difference whether I declare it separately or all together like I have it.

Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? For what it's worth, it already works in Chrome 11.0.696.3 (dev channel).

Comment: Looks OK for me using Chrome 11/Windows 7. I see 3 red minus signs as expected. One before the first `li`, one after the last `li` and one before the footer. And your CSS validates as CSS3 just fine :)

Comment: Using Chrome 10.0.648.133/osx 10.6. Could be my machine... I've not tested it elsewhere.

Comment: I can confirm that your issue happens with Chrome 10.0.648.134/Windows 7. So, it looks like it was a bug they've already fixed, but it's not been pushed to the Stable channel yet. I'll see if I can find a workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a Chrome bug. This works:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li id="blah">Three</li>
</ul>
<div id="footer">
  <p>This is a footer</p>
</div>
```

With CSS referencing the last element by ID:

```
ul { text-align: center; }   

#footer { text-align: center; margin-top: 200px;}

li:first-child:before, li:last-child:after, #footer:before {
   display: block;
   content: "-";
   color: red;
   margin: 10px 0;
}

#blah { }
```

If you remove the "#blah{}", reverts to buggy behavior.

EDIT: This has been fixed a long time ago in Chrome

Comment: +1, workaround works. How odd.

Comment: Works like a charm, I'll use this workaround until the updates roll out. Thanks Eric! On a side note, do you know why the blank id triggers the :after element?

Comment: I've added it the the Chrome bug in hopes that they can fix it.

Comment: Nice (and strange!) workaround. +1 from me

Comment: @Nathan - I don't know that, sorry.

Comment: year almost passed and the bug still exists... grr

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in Chrome, which has already been fixed in the Dev channel builds, so it's just a matter of time until it's fixed in Stable. (see the comments on this question)

Here's a bug report:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71213

Here's another one:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71052

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot for finding that. At least I know now it's the browser and not my code! :)